# Flag reason for "what does this pseudo code do"

Tags: support, flags, flag-reasons

I faced a question on Stack Overflow of someone who was just sharing *pseudo code*, and the question was: what is the output of that pseudo code? That's it and nothing else!

I know that this kind of questions should be flagged, but I was confused about the reason that I should put. Is it **off-topic**?

Comment: IMO *"Needs more focus"* or *"Needs debugging details"*, both are equal.

Comment: "Needs debugging details" is a more specific sub-category of "Needs details or clarity". The "Needs more focus" is a sibling reason to that and overlaps in a lot of cases. My personal way to determine which one to pick is the following: can you *comprehend* the question? If no, it's "needs clarity". If you can understand it and it's about a bug, but cannot answer because, say, data is missing, then it needs debugging details. If an answer would be too big, then it needs focus. But don't really think about it for too long - go with what seems correct and it would likely be applicable.